# ActionBlock appears to complete before I want it to

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I have an `ActionBlock` as part of my class:

```
private readonly ActionBlock<QueueMessage> block;
```

In the constructor, I initialize it like so:

```
block = new ActionBlock<QueueMessage>(async s => await Process(s),
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxParallelism });
```

My `Process` method is implemented as:

```
private async Task Process(QueueMessage message)
{
    using var tx = stateManager.CreateTransaction();

    var result = await processQueue.TryGetValueAsync(tx, message.Data.Checksum);
    if (!result.HasValue)
    {
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, $"Message {message.Data.Checksum} is being processed, but doesn't exist on the queue.");
        return;
    }

    try
    {
        await processorService.Process(message);
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Debug, $"Message {message.Data.Checksum} processed, removing from queue.");
        await processQueue.TryRemoveAsync(tx, message.Data.Checksum);
        await tx.CommitAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, $"Message {message.Data.Checksum} could not be processed, adding to retry queue.  Error: {e}");

        message.RetryCount++;
        await retryQueue.EnqueueAsync(tx, message);
    }
    finally
    {
        await tx.CommitAsync();
    }
}
```

When I get a message I want to process, I call:

```
// Process the message
if (!await block.SendAsync(message, cancellationToken))
{
    logger.Log(LogLevel.Error, $"Failed to enqueue data with checksum {message.Data.Checksum}");
}
```

This works the first time, and the message is processed perfectly.  The second message I get (maybe a few seconds later, maybe a minute later, depends on the load of the system), then `block.SendAsync` immediately returns false.  No code in `Process` is ran.  When I look at this under the debugger, I notice `block.IsCompleted` is true.  However, I never called `block.Complete();` or anything.

Why is my block complete when I still might have more work for it to do?  Thanks!

**Update: I might have a clue.**

I seem to be hitting this breakpoint (In the ActionBlock.cs source code)

[image]

Comment: Do you have any other blocks in a pipeline, that the block is faulted indicates that something somewhere is throwing an exception out of a block and faulting it.

Comment: @JSteward Yea, no other blocks in the pipeline.  But yes, my action was throwing an exception (which my debugger wasn't nice enough to tell me about) which apparently makes your entire block useless.  I've fixed the exception and also adding more try/catch code, and it now works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery solved.  My Action was throwing an unhandled exception, which apparently marks the block as complete and doesn't allow any new messages.

I'd be interested if there's any way to control this behavior, or if it's recommended to always have `try/catch` blocks around your action.

Comment: Yeah this is standard behavior, if you don't you want your block to fault always catch all exceptions. If any exception is thrown from the block it becomes faulted. There isn't any option for this behavior either.